# How to use separate css and js for dashboard

Tags: angular

I have a project in Angular 11. For the project, I used a AdminLTE (a theme of CSS and JS) for the whole application.

In the styles.scss, I have:

```
@import '~admin-lte/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
@import '~admin-lte/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css';
@import '~admin-lte/plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css';
@import '~admin-lte/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap.min.css';
@import '~admin-lte/dist/css/adminlte.min.css';
@import '~admin-lte/plugins/overlayScrollbars/css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css';
@import '~admin-lte/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.css';
@import '~admin-lte/plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css';
```

While in angular.json, I have:

```
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js",
          "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
          "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/chart.js/Chart.min.js",
          "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/sparklines/sparkline.js",
          "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jqvmap/jquery.vmap.min.js",
          "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.usa.js",
          "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jquery-knob/jquery.knob.min.js",
          "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.js",
          "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/bs-custom-file-input/bs-custom-file-input.min.js"
        ]
```

But now I want to use a separate theme for the dashboard only:

```
asset/main.css
asset/main.js
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the js file, you need to add it to the scripts array in angular.json
then add in typings.d.ts (create this file in src if it does not already exist)

```
declare var variableName:any;
```

Import it in your file as

```
import * as variable from 'variableName';
```

for css again inside angular.json add:

```
"styles": [
  "asset/main.css"
],
```

Then you can import it in the dashboard scss file

```
@import 'main.scss';
```